# print "text" when the field is empty in csv file

Tags: php, arrays, csv

observe the code

```
if($line[$x]==1 and !empty($cat_ids[$x]))
    array_push($cat1,$cat_ids[$x]);
    elseif($line[$x]==1 and $cat_ids[$x]="")
    array_push($cat1,"id not allocated");
```

`$line[$x]` contains 1 and `$cat_ids[$x]` contains the id.

when the id is empty, i want to push "id not allocated" into the array at that particular `$line[$x]`. Please help me...

the code i written is skipping the empty field instead of printing 'id not allocated'

Comment: If you have a problem with your code, you should start with debugging it. Also it normally start with properly indenting the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
elseif($line[$x]==1 and $cat_ids[$x]="")
```

to

```
elseif($line[$x]==1 and $cat_ids[$x]=="")
```

as `$cat_ids[$x]=""` statement will assign the value null to `$cat_ids[$x]`

Answer (score 0):

First store the outcome of the decision, then assign the new value based on that outcome:

```
$filled = ($line[$x] == 1 and !empty($cat_ids[$x]));
$cat1[] = $filled ? $cat_ids[$x] : "id not allocated";
```

As this stores to variables you can easily debug this as well:

```
$filled = ($line[$x] == 1 and !empty($cat_ids[$x]));
var_dump($filled);
$cat1[] = $filled ? $cat_ids[$x] : "id not allocated";
```

So you can better check if the code actually does what you expect.